# How to filter the value of the key in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a array that contain different keys and i want to filter the key based on the value TRUE OR FALSE.
I am in trouble please help.

Here is my code

```
 foreach ($combine as $data) {
       unset($data['user_name'], $data['date']);
       if (array_values($data) == TRUE) {
            pr(array_keys($data));
       }
  }
```

Here is the array

```
 Array
    (
        [microsoft] => FALSE
        [health_care] => TRUE
        [nasa_cerification_type_i] => TRUE
        [nasa_cerification_type_ii] => TRUE
        [nasa_cerification_type_iii] => TRUE
    )
```

Comment: foreach can be used like this `foreach ($var as $key => $value`

Comment: @frz3993 yes i forgot this now it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
foreach($combine as $data){
    unset($data['user_name'], $data['date']); //we don't need these
    $valid = [];
    foreach($data as $n => $v){
        if($v === true){ //be careful! Are the values really boolean? then use ===, otherwise use ==
            $valid[] = $n;
        }
    }
    //do something with $valid
    print_r($valid); //etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$trueArray=array_filter($array, function ($ar){

return ($ar==true);

});


$falseArray=array_filter($array, function ($ar){

return ($ar==false);

});


print_r($trueArray);
```